# Editing and saving an XML file, vb.net

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have a major project at school.

I've developed a program that creates and stores data, in this case "customer records". However I've hit a crossroad as I can't seem to program anything that allows me to edit the data within the XML file from the program.

Obviously I can manually do this through going through the debug folder, opening the XML file and changing it. But this defeats the purpose

I know how to add a new file, which I've successfully done. But can't seem to edit the current "customer record".

I've created a function where all customer records and displayed in a text box. I specifically want this text box to become editable when a button is clicked. Then for it to be saved to the XML file.

Here's an image for a bit of a guider for my vision

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QOF9.jpg)

Comment: Look into [**XML Serialization**](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/292726/Serialization-Part-III-XML-Serialization).

Comment: The best way in this case is to put the data into a Datatable so it can be view easily.  Putting into classes would require an extra steps of moving the data from classes to the control and back.  You may be able to use the DataTable ReadXml/SaveXml  methods depending on the structure of the xml file.  Once the data is in the DataTable you can use the DataGridView DataSource method to display the data in the view or use a bind method if you are not use a DGV,

Comment: @jdweng : Didn't know that. Good suggestion!

Answer (score -1):

Generally speaking you need to:

- Find how to set a text box editable or not (this is the easiest part, hint: There's a `readonly` property)
- Parse the content of the textbox back into your xml (this may be the hardest part since it'll incorporate parsing the various data types (dates, times, numbers, ...)
- Save the XML to a file (not hard, but, not as easy as setting a single property :) )

Make a new question if you need help for a specific part.

Comment: If you implement [**XML Serialization**](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/292726/Serialization-Part-III-XML-Serialization) all parsing is done for you by the framework, so it actually doesn't have to be _**that**_ hard. :)

Comment: True, he might skip the data type parsing if he makes a class with all string properties, but I'd assume that'd be frowned upon.

Comment: Might be, but it all comes down to what the XML file requires (which he haven't shown us, making this pure guesswork). But there are both [**`TryParse()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1(v=vs.110).aspx) methods and native controls (such as the [**`DateTimePicker`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker(v=vs.110).aspx)) for handling such input, so he's at least got many, rather simple options which include error handling.